# How do I revert an unpublished deletion of a workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, project-online

I have opened a production SPO site in SPD. The site is part of Office 365 and is a Project Online site. I deleted a site workflow in the editor, but have not saved the change, nor published it. Assuming I understand how publishing works, that should mean that the change only exists locally on my computer and that the sharepoint.com site is not changed.

However, even after closing SPD and reopening it, and using F5 to refresh the program, I cannot see the deleted workflow (which I did not want to delete). I have looked in the recycle bin and it is not there either.

I have tried to find the answer to this myself, but every search I try returns results where published changes are not reflected on the live site, which is quite possibly the exact opposite of my problem (I don't know how to tell for sure, but the workflow no longer appears in the dropdown when editing or creating project types, though all project types currently associated with it still appear to be so).

My question is how can I restore the workflow so that I can edit it in SPD, and is the change somehow propagated to sharepoint.com even though I never published the project after deleting the workflow? The restoration of the workflow would also, ideally, allow all existing projects using it to continue to use it at their current stage.

Answer (score 1):

Your only hope is if it's in the site recycle bin. If not, then unfortunately there is no way to restore it besides manually rebuilding it.

Comment: If I manually rebuild it, how do I go about re-linking the existing projects to it, or do I need to? Also, I have a dev version that is mostly the same, how can I copy that and use it as a starting point? Google provides some results, but they seem to all apply to SP 2010 and utilize Visual Studio - it seems that in the intervening years (and versions) they would have made it easier, or at least I'm hoping so...